# ListVIew not showing up in my Layout, Android Studios

Tags: java, android

I'm trying out this Udacity course and need help. Why isn't my list showing up in my fragment. Please Help!

```
            package com.example.landon.sunshine.app;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.ListView;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Arrays;
            import java.util.List;


            /**
             * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
             */
            public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

                public MainActivityFragment() {
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    String[] forecastArray = {

                            "Today - Sunny - 54/89",
                            "Tomorrow - Cloudy - 45/60",
                            "Wednesday - Sunny - 66/77",
                            "Thursday - Sunny - 67/89",
                            "Friday - Sunny - 77/95",
                            "Saturday - Rain - 50/70",
                            "Sunday - Sunny - 67/88"
                    };

                    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                            Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

                    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(

                            getActivity(),

                            R.layout.list_item_forecast,

                            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,

                            weekForecast

                    );

                    Activity rootView = null;

                    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
                            R.id.listview_forecast);
                    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,          container, false);
                }
            }
```

I'm new to java and new to android, hence the learning. I really hope someone can help.

I'm not even sure what it's wants me to say more of. I am studying this course and it's driving me insane. I have done this for several days looking for the errors and havent found too much of anything. But I have faith in this community, because this community taught me all my mistakes in javascript and css. Thank You

Comment: The problem might be `Activity rootView = null;

                    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
                            R.id.listview_forecast);` There is a similar issue posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848637/udacity-android-first-lesson-listview-doesnt-show-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your getView method

use a view which inflates your layout and use this view to declare the listview and return the same view at the end of GetView() method.You can use like this,

```
  @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,  container, false);

     String[] forecastArray = {

                            "Today - Sunny - 54/89",
                            "Tomorrow - Cloudy - 45/60",
                            "Wednesday - Sunny - 66/77",
                            "Thursday - Sunny - 67/89",
                            "Friday - Sunny - 77/95",
                            "Saturday - Rain - 50/70",
                            "Sunday - Sunny - 67/88"
                    };

      List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                            Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

                    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(

                            getActivity(),

                            R.layout.list_item_forecast,

                            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,

                            weekForecast

                    );



                    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(
                            R.id.listview_forecast);
                    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

                    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Activity rootView = null;
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);
```

to:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);;
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

return rootView ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);
```

and

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't see your ListView because you're inflating your layout file twice. You first inflated it at:

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`

and again at:

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`

Therefore you're inflating your layout, initialising it, then returning a newly-inflated layout. That's why you don't see it.

You should just do `return view` instead, like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,  container, false);

    .
    .
    .

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your rootView to null `rootView = null;` and you'r trying to get the `ListView` from a `null` object `rootView.findViewById()`, you'll have a **NullPointerException** here.

Also `rootView` should be an instance of `View` not an `Activity`.

Change your code like that:

```
 public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

           String[] forecastArray = {
                                "Today - Sunny - 54/89",
                                "Tomorrow - Cloudy - 45/60",
                                "Wednesday - Sunny - 66/77",
                                "Thursday - Sunny - 67/89",
                                "Friday - Sunny - 77/95",
                                "Saturday - Rain - 50/70",
                                "Sunday - Sunny - 67/88"
                        };

           View rootView;


          public MainActivityFragment() {}

          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                 rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

                 List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

                 ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                getActivity(),
                                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                                weekForecast);


                  ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);

                  listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

                  return rootView;
          }
}
```